# Си. Посимвольное считывание строки, с наполнением массива слов

Tags: c, массивы, символы

В чем ошибка в коде ниже.
Идея элементарная - вводится строка, при считывании строка разбивается на слова, так что на выходе есть массив[i] слов. Разделитель слов - пробел.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j=0;
    char **words; //массив указателей на слова
    char c; //заготовка под чтение символов

    words = (char**)calloc(1,sizeof(char*)); //исходный размер массива
    words[i] = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));//исходный размер слова

    printf("\n Enter the line... \n");
    while ((c=getchar())!='\n') //считываем посимвольно пока не наткнемся на конец строки
    {
        if (c!=' '){ //если это не пробел, то
            words[i]=(char*)realloc(words[i],(i+1)*sizeof(char)); //увеличиваем размер текущего слова word[i] на i+1
            words[i][j] = c;//присваиваем текущему элементу слова значение считанного символа
            j++;//увеличиваем счетчик на 1
        }
        else{//иначе,
            words[i][j] = '\0';//присваиваем последнему элементу в слове символ конца слова
            j=0;//обнуляем счетчик элементов в слове
            i++;//увеличиваем счетчик слов на 1
            words = (char**)realloc(words,i*sizeof(char*)); //увеличиваем размер массива слов на 1
        }
        ...//здесь вывод слов "слово[1] .., слово [2]", но ошибка выше
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе одного символа - все хорошо (выводится этот символ), если же вводится, три символа с пробелом (например "1 1") - ошибка: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. –

Comment: Нельзя ли мне, недостойному, нижайше испросить у многоуважаемого автора вопроса, что происходит при выполнении данной гениальнейшей программы? И не будет ли любезен многоуважаемый автор добавить сие в вышеупомянутый вопрос?..

Comment: Просто пытаюсь понять как сделать это на Си. Я никогда раньше с Си не сталкивался.

Comment: Ошибка-то в чём проявляется?

Comment: при вводе 1 символа - все хорошо (выводится этот символ), если же вводится, три символа с пробелом (например "1 1") - ошибка:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ошибка в строке `words[i]=(char*)realloc(words[i],(i+1)*sizeof(char));`.
   размер строки хранится в j, так что нужно `... (j+1)*sizeof ...`
2. Ошибка в строке `words = (char**)realloc(words,i*sizeof(char*));`.
   Поскольку i-индекс последнего слова, памяти надо на один указатель больше -- `... (i+1)*sizeof(char*) ...`.
3. После этого под новое слово нужно запросить новую память: `words[i] = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));`
4. Ну и нигде нет проверки на нехватку памяти (это когда calloc/realloc вернёт 0), при этом программа завершится с ошибкой обращения по нулевому адресу.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! 
Также у меня пропущена строка с добавлением '\0' в последнее слово, после выхода из цикла.
Про память Вы тоже правы абсолютно, но это для для меня следующий шаг.